# [Javascript; Google Earth Engines} Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and UInt16

Tags: javascript, spatial, geotiff

I'm trying to just export a simple AOI of a Landsat-8 image, but I'm getting the error in the title. Why? The bands are all floats so I don't see the issue?

```
var polygon = 
/* color: #ffc82d */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-3.8916300564568784, 58.548252075724285],
      [-3.8916300564568784, 58.534321246028455],
      [-3.872489812926605, 58.534321246028455],
      [-3.872489812926605, 58.548252075724285]]], null, false),

images = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA");
var image = ee.Image(images.filterDate('2016-05-01', '2020-07-01').filterBounds(polygon).sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());

Export.image.toDrive({

  image: image,
  description: "site",
  region:polygon,
  scale: 30,

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have  different kinds of data type, so you can't stack bands to save as a unique raster. You can convert data type or to select bands with the same data kind to solve this issue (taking the second choice)